# Access denied | uncaught exception in FF 2.0 | servlet call from another host

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-domain

Seems like got stuck in the cross domain issue.

Just trying to get the XML response from the servlet call through POST
method:

$.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "http://10.210.221.43:9081/shopsfinder/servlet/
ShopsFinderStoreServlet" //THIS DOESN'T
//url: "../ShopsFinderStoreServlet" //IT WORKS
..................

It works fine when we place the servlet at the same location where our
application server is, with the relative path.

BUT we have to put the servlet somewhere else means [at some other
location], due to some limitations.

Then it doesn't hit the servlet and we don't give any response back to
the browser and it goes in error function as given:

```
                    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            alert("errror XMLHttpRequest: " + XMLHttpRequest.responseXML + "textStatus: " + textStatus + "  errorThrown: " +errorThrown);
                            }
```

Which gives all the values NULL and get the exception in FF.

Do we have any work around to overcome this issue?

Many thanks
Mohammed Arif

Comment: Exceptions are XMLHttpRequest: null failure code 0x80004005 ns_error_failure etc.

Answer (score 0):

Cross Domain Access are initially disabled by most browsers for security reasons. To overcome this issue you must enable Cross Domain Access or perhaps implements Ajax Proxies.

Answer (score 0):

Because of some reason, we couldn't use proxy.

But we have overcome the issue, we have used Open Hub AJAX API which solved cross domain problem, now everything has been working fine.

Comment: instead of adding an answer, you should edit your first post for keeping the thread more readable.
If you want to respond to a particular answer, just comment it. (link `add comment` under the answer)